# Do ADHD stimulants harm a brain in the long run?

Tags: adhd, add-adhd

Do ADHD stimulants like [Ritalin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methylphenidate) harm a brain in the long run? What is the safe level per day when using Ritalin?

Comment: Hi Ahmet Sou, welcome to Medical Sciences. Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in [the help center](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: I would add that this question would be more appropriate on Psychology&Neuroscience.SE, but the lack of prior research needs to be corrected before it can be migrated there.